# how to add validate rules

Tags: laravel, validation

I tried to add `unique validation rule` in controller.
but why the duplicate data still record to database.

**Controller**

```php
public function tambahDataWNI(Request $request){
    $validation = $request->validate([
        'no_identitas' => 'required|unique:pendataan,no_identitas'
    ]);

    $c = new InputdatawniModel();
    $c->jenis_identitas = $request->jenis_identitas;
    $c->no_identitas = $request->no_identitas;
    $c->nama = $request->nama;
    $c->asal_shelter = $request->asal_shelter;
    $c->save();

    return redirect('inputdatawni');
}
```

Comment: is your table name 'pendataan' correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look on here [unique rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique)

based on that reference you need to make sure that you use correct table name and correct column name

```
$validation = $request->validate([
    'no_identitas' => 'required|unique:table_name,column_name'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sperate request file for this

```
 public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'POST':
        return [
            'no_identitas' => 'required|unique:tablename,columnname,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
        ];
        case 'PUT':
            $model = Model::whereId($this->model)->first();

        return [

        'no_identitas' => 'required|numeric|unique:tablename,name,' . $model->id . ',id',deleted_at,NULL',

        ];
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Below validator class in your controller.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

And Check with below code.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
         [
            'no_identitas'=>'required|unique:your_tablename'
         ]);

if($validator->fails())
{
   // Error if any
}else{
  // No Errors
}
```

Comment: this is ain't no different with op code other than make a custom manual validation, here reference for what i mean https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators